# Serializing a nested json object into an opened Utf8JsonWriter

Tags: c#, json, json-serialization

While serializing with `Utf8JsonWriter`, I want to add a field which is a complex object. I want to just serialize it like a nested json:

```
public override void Write(Utf8JsonWriter writer, Foo foo, JsonSerializerOptions options)
{
    writer.WriteStartObject();
    writer.WriteString("simpleField1", "value1");
    writer.WriteString("simpleField2", "value2");
    ....
    writer.WriteString("bar", JsonSerializer.Serialize(foo.Bar));
    ....
    writer.WriteEndObject();
    writer.Flush();
}
```

This results in any quotes being escaped to `\u0022`, however. How can I properly add an already serialized object while writing in `Utf8JsonWriter`?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Found the answer eventually, I just need to give the writer to the serializer:

```
writer.WritePropertyName("bar");
JsonSerializer.Serialize(writer, foo.Bar);
```

This resulted exactly in what I need.

Comment: I didn't find that in the docu, it is kind of lacking. so i very much appreciate your post! ... its neither https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/standard/serialization/system-text-json/converters-how-to?pivots=dotnet-6-0 nor here https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.text.json.utf8jsonwriter?view=net-7.0